# WARNING in vuetify/lib export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I installed Vuetify in a vue-laravel project. I'm not using vue cli. The node modules I installed were:

- vuetify
- vuetify-loader
- sass-loader

I followed this tutorial: [Setup Laravel with Vue and Vuetify](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VaI9tV8GQFk)
I have this in my webpack.mix.js:

```
const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin')
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin')
var webpackConfig = {
    plugins: [
        new VuetifyLoaderPlugin(),
        new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin()
    ]
}
```

In my plugins folder i have a file vuetify.js with this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
    icons: {
      iconfont: 'md',  // 'mdi' || 'mdiSvg' || 'md' || 'fa' || 'fa4'
    },
    theme: {
      dark: false,
    },
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: "#4682b4",
        secondary: "#b0bec5",
        accent: "#8c9eff",
        error: "#b71c1c",
      },
    },
  })
```

In my app.js this:

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('alpinejs');
require('livewire-vue');

import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css';
import { plugin } from 'postcss';
import 'livewire-vue'
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from "../plugins/vuetify"
Vue.use(Vuetify);
```

and this is part of a vue file linked with a laravel blade view

```
new Vue({
    el: '#facility',
    vuetify: Vuetify,
    data: () => ({
        url: dir,
        search: '',
}),
```

My problem is when I type **npm run dev** it returns 55 warnings like this one:
*WARNING in ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/util/mixins.js 4:9-19
export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'*.
The ones that I can read in console are from vuetify/lib and in the blade view some components works well like the grid systems an others doesn't work at all as v-rating. Colors as primary, error or warning doesn't work.

##### Versions:

"@mapbox/mapbox-sdk": "^0.13.3",
"case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "^2.4.0",
"chart.js": "^3.5.1",
"mapbox-gl": "^0.53.1",
"mapbox-gl-vue": "^2.0.4",
"vform": "^2.1.0",
"vue": "^3.2.31",
"vue-axios": "^3.2.4",
"vue-mapbox": "^0.4.1",
"vue-router": "^3.5.1",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
"vuetify": "^2.6.5",
"vuetify-loader": "^1.7.3",
"vuex": "^3.6.2"
Laravel 8

Comment: Well you have vue3 installed but your code shows vue2 syntax, you need to install the correcty vuetify version and update your code if you really want to use vue3, or install vue2 instead if you want to stay on vue2. I think the tutorial you are using is quite old, try to find another one with vue3 syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code share, you installed Vue 3

```
"vue": "^3.2.31",
```

Currently Vuetify not supporting for the Vue 3.

Check with following link.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/introduction/roadmap/